# Crontab not sending php reminder email to the right person

Tags: php, email, cron

I try to develop a new feature that the system can send email to users one day before their reservations are expired. 
I wrote a php script, and used the crontab to trigger the execution of the php file every morning.
Now the problem is that if I compile the php file, everything works fine, and the emails are sent to the users. When I check the maillog, it telling

```
to=<useremail@email.com>, ctladdr=<blablala> (0/0), delay=00:04:12, xdelay=00:04:12, mailer=esmtp, pri=120371, relay=XXXXXXX., stat=Sent (r3HMoisd031604 Message accepted for delivery)
```

But if I used crontab to execute the same php file, the mail is sent to root of the server, but not "useremail@email.com" as I wrote in the php file.

```
to=<root@myserver.com>, ctladdr=<blablabla> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30958, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

What can be the problem of it? why the php file doesn't work as expected from crontab? Anyone can help?

My php file -- "demo.php"

```
require_once "defaultincludes.inc";
global $tbl_entry, $tbl_users;

$current =  mktime(date("H"),date("i"),0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
$start = $current + 12*3600;
$end = $current + 40*3600;

$query="SELECT U.email, U.fullname, E.name  FROM $tbl_entry E, $tbl_users U "
       ." WHERE U.name = E.create_by "
       ." AND E.end_time >= $start "
       ." AND E.end_time <= $end ";
$result= sql_query($query);
$mail_list=array();
for ($i=0; ($row=sql_row_keyed($result,$i));$i++)
{
    $temp=array();
    $temp[]=$row['fullname'];
    $temp[]=$row['email'];
    $temp[]=$row['name'];
    $mail_list[]=$temp;
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($mail_list); $i++) {
    $to = $mail_list[$i][1];
    $subject= "Reminder of ".$mail_list[$i][2];
    $body = "Hi ".$mail_list[$i][0].",\n"
             ." Your reservation ".$mail_list[$i][2]." will expire in one day";
    mail($to,$subject,$body);
}
```

crontab file -- "reminder.txt"

```
30 7 * * * /var/www/html/qars-vm90/demo.php
```

Comment: you don't need 2 loops and a standard while() would be much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/var/www/html/qars-vm90/demo.php
```

Will only work if the script is marked as executable. In addition you'd need a shebang at the top of the file to tell the shell what to do with the file (should it execute it with perl, php, python, ...)

I suspect that the email sent is an error message from cron saying that the file is not executable. If you login as root you should be able to read that message.

The simplest possible change is probably to change your crontab to

```
30 7 * * * php /var/www/html/qars-vm90/demo.php
```

It's also worth remembering that cron's environment is often slight different to what you get at the command line (login shells and all that)

Comment: haha, yeah, I also figured out the problem yesterday, it's because I missed the "php" command in front of the file name. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to answer your question. Where does the php script get the email address from? What user does it run as normally, and what user does it run as from cron?

Comment: Yeah, that's not making sense to me. Validate that you don't have a user who gave root@myserver.com as their email address?